# $\frac{a}{1+b}+\frac{b}{1+c}+\frac{c}{1+d}+\frac{d}{1+a}+abcd\leq 3$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c,d\in[0,1]$. Show that $$\frac{a}{1+b}+\frac{b}{1+c}+\frac{c}{1+d}+\frac{d}{1+a}+abcd\leq 3$$

My idea: It's enough to prove that  $\frac{a}{1+b}+\frac{b}{1+c}+\frac{c}{1+d}+\frac{d}{1+a}+abcd+1\leq a+b+c+d\Leftrightarrow \frac{ab}{1+b}+\frac{bc}{1+c}+\frac{cd}{1+d}+\frac{da}{1+a} \geq abcd+1$. Now I am stuck

Comment: While you correctly observe that it would be enough to prove that the original left hand side plus $1$ is at most $a+b+c+d$ (e.g. because $a+b+c+d$ is at most $1+1+1+1=4$, which is the original right hand side plus $1$), this stronger inequality is not always true, as one can see e.g. by taking $b=c=d=0$, where it asserts that $a+1 \leq a$. So one must abandon any attempt to prove this stronger inequality.